# FileNet property for all versions of a document

Tags: plugins, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

As I understand it in FileNet each version of a document gets its own ID. And if you create a new version then usually the properties are inherited from the previous version. So each version of a document has its own values for the properties.

Now I would like to add a property which is valid for all versions of a document (all versions != document class) for the use in a plugin. But I couldn't find any support for this. The only ugly concept I could come up with is the following:

1. Add a new property
2. Add all information to the lowest version of the document and retrieve it from there (otherwise you would need to modify all versions on changes)
3. Add a subscription which empties the property when creating the 2nd version (0.2, 1.0 or 1.1 usually) of the document and prevents deletion of the oldest version

Is there a more intelligent way?

Comment: What do you mean by "property valid for all versions of a document"?

Comment: Lets say I have document class X, I create a new documents of this class with content test.txt (version 0.1) now I promote (v1.0) and do a checkout and checkin (v1.1) to get two new documents. But those documents belong all to the same version series and if I change a property in one version it doesn't affect others (what is indeed the desired behaviour usually), but I would like to have one global property for all those versions, but not global per document class, it is per version series.

Comment: Maybe I could create my own object and a subscription that creates an object when the initial version is created. That would be quite nice compared to the other approach.

Comment: Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: @swepss It could have many applicances, the idea when asking the question was for permanent document links. Just making the relation document A to B and not A version x to B version y. This could be used to develop a plugin which can display certain relations between documents. E.g. a specification, a glossary, a documentation and some other files which are there in each project.

Comment: @swepss I know you could try to use the folders to structure projects, but I would like to have something more general than the dossier plugin example, supporting unknown structure. With that plugin it would be possible to get an UML-like view over the document relations independent from the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a special Version series property - Version series **IS** that property.

Most of the time you only care about the current version of the document which can be accessed through any version of the document or its Version series. If that is not the case then you will have to iterate through all the versions of the document which are, again, most conveniently accessed through the Version series.

Since any document at any point of time is associated with its VS, when you need a relation to the VS you must use VS object reference or its ID.

Comment: So you say you could add a property to the version series instead of the document?

Comment: No, I am saying that all you need is the VS ID. VS is what binds all versions of a document - both API wise and business logic wise.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I see how this can be used to create links between VS. However the last link is still missing to accept: how do I add a property which is the same for all versions? E.g. a collection of helpful web-links opposed to a property added to the version which changes over time e.g. the project (I could imagine a major version is created at the end of the project and the cycle starts again). Is this done by creating a new document type with the global properties and then create a link between the version series (creating a new doc with the global props on create)?

Comment: You can do that by making the property settable only on create. Then the value you set when you create the first version will propagate to all the other versions should there be any. However, a collection of helpful web-links sounds like something more than one document can use. You can create a Custom class to represent the helpful link entity and refer to its instances from any document.